# Replacing values of a dataframe column with a vector

Tags: r, indexing

I want to simplify my current method of replacing column values of a dataframe with a vector. I've provided a reproducible answer below with my solution using base R. A simplified version contains just one data frame and with multiple dataframes, i'm forced to use a for loop due to my bad solution.

How can I simplify my approach?

```
# Simplified version
Df <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3),
           b = c(4,5,6),
           c = c(7,8,9))

l <- list(c(11,22,33),
          c(44,55,66))

letters <- c("a","b")

Df[letters] <- l


# Multiple data frames
Df1 <- list(data.frame(a = c(1,2,3),
                       b = c(4,5,6),
                       c = c(7,8,9)),
            data.frame(a = c(101,102,103),
                       b = c(104,105,106),
                       c = c(107,108,109)))
l <- list( list(c(11,22,33), c(44,55,66)),
           list(c(111,222,333), c(444,555,666)) )

letters <- c("a","b")

for(i in 1:length(Df1)){

  Df1[[i]][letters] <- l[[i]]

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an option with `map2`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
map2(Df1, l, ~ {.x[letters] <- .y; .x})
```

Or with `inset` from `magrittr`

```
library(magrittr)
map2(Df1, l, ~  inset(.x, letters, value = .y))
```

or in a chain

```
map2(Df1, l, ~ .x %>% 
                 select(-one_of(letters)) %>% 
                 bind_cols(.y %>% 
                               set_names(letters)) %>% 
                 select(names(.x)))
```

---

Or in `base R`

```
Map(function(x, y) {x[letters] <- y;x},  Df1, l)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This seems very complicated when  compared to my for loop. For readability, would your solution be considered a better approach/easier to read for an experienced R user?

Comment: @Ali You asked for a solution with `dplyr`.  If it is okay for a `base R`, then I can change to more simpler ways

Comment: I think that would be more appropriate as I assumed using dplyr would simplify this. I’ll change my question accordingly

Comment: @Ali Thanks.  I changed the code.  Now, it is one-liner, but I used the earlier code so that it would be in a chain instead of wrapping within `{}`

Comment: Thank you for your multiple solutions. I try my best before posting on SO to figure out solutions myself but it seems there are many possibilities which I am unfamiliar with. Any advice on how I can proceed next time I am stuck on a similar problem?

Comment: @Ali If you are really interested in learning, 1) then it would be first to try with all the available functions you know. 2) don't worry about mistakes - because mistakes register more in brain than getting a solution easily from others, 3) google for solutions - here keyword is the most important.  Even with that, it may be difficult sometimes to find a topic that you wanted.  Anyway, try that and even if that doesn't solve, then post on SO.  In this way, you have attempted a lot and this you won't forget

Comment: @Ali In addition to that, try solving problems others post on SO and post as your solution.  This would go into an immediate feedback from others (both positive and negative).  Sometimes, negative feedback really energizes and make you better as a programmer

Comment: much much appreciated for this advice. I’ll take this all into account and hopefully next time will be a more complex question for you :) thank you.